# Rewrite URL while keeping parameters via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite a URL for a PHP file, while keeping the parameters that's passed by that PHP file. Is this possible?

The url is
`https://example.com/newpoints.php?action=XXX`

In my .htaccess I have
`RewriteRule ^shop\.php\?action=([^./]+)$ newpoints.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

I've tried variations of that RewriteRule, but can't get it to work. I'm testing with https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

Comment: `RewriteRule` matches against the path component of the URL only, so your pattern there will never match. You need to match `^shop\.php$` only, nothing more - the use of the `QSA`flag will see to it, that the query string of the requested URL gets appended to your substitution URL.

Comment: @CBroe after changing it to `RewriteRule ^shop\.php$ newpoints.php?action=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` I'm still not able to get it to match.

Comment: Which is the URL that is actually requested by the browser? That is visible in the browser's URL field?

Comment: Did you enable such rewrites? Have you read about what the `AllowOverride` directive does?

Comment: @arkascha The requested URL is shown in the original question. I have `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: The only URL you have shown is `https://example.com/newpoints.php?action=XXX`. If that is your _incoming_ URL, that you wanted to rewrite, your rule of course doesn't match it.

Comment: I suspected exactly what @CBroe points out: that you implemented your rule the wrong way round. Your rule needs to match the incoming URL (the path of that URL) and rewrite to the internal resource.